# R Shiny: Actionbutton to dynamically create bucket_list from selectizeInput

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a `bucket_list` that populates from a `selectizeInput`.

I am hoping to prevent the `bucket_list` populating until the `actionButton` is clicked, at which point the `selectizeInput` should also reset to empty.

It currently only functions to reset both, which is not ideal.

Please see the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(sortable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("duplicate"),
  actionButton('add','Confirm Selected Number(s)'),

  uiOutput("groups"),
 
  column(
    width = 4,
    # bin
    tags$div(
      class = "panel panel-default",
      tags$div(
        class = "panel-heading",
        icon("trash"),
        "Remove Number"
      ),
      tags$div(
        class = "panel-body",
        id = "sortable_bin"
      )
    )
    
  ),
  sortable_js(
    "sortable_bin",
    options = sortable_options(
      group = list(
        group = "sortGroup1",
        put = TRUE,
        pull = TRUE
      ),
      onAdd = htmlwidgets::JS("function (evt) { this.el.removeChild(evt.item); }")
    )
  )

  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  numbers = (c(1:5))
  
  output$duplicate = renderUI(selectizeInput("for_duplication", "For Duplication", choices = numbers, multiple = T,options=list(create=TRUE,'plugins' = list('remove_button'))))
  

  observeEvent(input$add,{updateSelectInput(session,"for_duplication", choices= numbers, 
                                            selected = character(0))})
  
  
  output$groups = renderUI({bucket_list(
    header = "",
    group_name = "rank_groups",
    orientation = "horizontal",
    
    add_rank_list(
      text = h5("Starting Group"),
      input_id = "start",
      labels = numbers),
    
    add_rank_list(
      text = h5("Duplicated"),
      input_id = "duplicate",
      labels = input$for_duplication))})
  
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general for this kind of thing I would use `eventReactive` in place of the `observeEvent` and use that reactive variable as the `labels` in your `add_rank_list`, but for some reason when I did that the bucket list wouldn't render without clicking the 'add' action button and I wasn't able to figure out why. As an alternative, you can use a `reactive` with a check on `input$add` instead:

```
library(shiny)
library(sortable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("duplicate"),
  actionButton('add','Confirm Selected Number(s)'),
  
  uiOutput("groups"),
  
  column(
    width = 4,
    # bin
    tags$div(
      class = "panel panel-default",
      tags$div(
        class = "panel-heading",
        icon("trash"),
        "Remove Number"
      ),
      tags$div(
        class = "panel-body",
        id = "sortable_bin"
      )
    )
    
  ),
  sortable_js(
    "sortable_bin",
    options = sortable_options(
      group = list(
        group = "sortGroup1",
        put = TRUE,
        pull = TRUE
      ),
      onAdd = htmlwidgets::JS("function (evt) { this.el.removeChild(evt.item); }")
    )
  )
  
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  numbers <- c(1:5)
  
  output$duplicate = renderUI(selectizeInput("for_duplication", "For Duplication", choices = numbers, multiple = T,options=list(create=TRUE,'plugins' = list('remove_button'))))
  
  confirmed_numbers <- reactive({
    if (input$add == 0) {
      NULL
    } else {
      updateSelectInput(session, "for_duplication", choices = numbers, selected = character(0))
      isolate(input$for_duplication)
    }
  })
  
  output$groups = renderUI({
    
    bucket_list(
      header = "",
      group_name = "rank_groups",
      orientation = "horizontal",
      
      add_rank_list(
        text = h5("Starting Group"),
        input_id = "start",
        labels = numbers),
      
      add_rank_list(
        text = h5("Duplicated"),
        input_id = "duplicate",
        labels = confirmed_numbers()))
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks very much, @mr-putter.